# Submitting a request in Laravel and sending mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to submit a form and send an email based on data submitted through the form, but it doesn't seem to be working because I don't get back the success message.

**Controller**

```php
public function contact(Request $request)
{
    $request = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required| email',
        'message' => 'required | max:1000',
    ]);

    Mail::to('support@mail.com')->send(new contact($request));

    return redirect()->back()->with("success", "You email has successfully been sent");
}
```

**Form**

```php
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
<form action="/contact" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" required name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-black no-margin-bottom btn-small" 
        type="submit">Contact</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
`Route::post('/contact', 'HomeController@contact');`
```

Comment: Can you dd($request) before the email please?

Comment: Did you see anything in storage/logs/laravel.log ?

Comment: is your route correctly method of POST? check your csrf token is it included or not? try `dd` before validate function.

Comment: Yes I added dd($request) and got the request data back. I checked the storage/logs/laravel.log and there nothing there and yes route method is post

Answer (score 0):

If you're being redirected back to the form page without error messages or your sucess flash message then I am inclined to think the problem is in your template. Assuming you are using the laracasts/flash package your method should look like this

```
public function contact(Request $request)
{
    $request = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required| email',
        'message' => 'required | max:1000'
    ]);

    Mail::to('support@mail.com')->send(
         new contact($request)
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with("success", "You email has successfully been sent");
}
```

redirect()->with() adds data to the session but it doesn't display a message unless you manually do so in the template like this

```
@if (session('sucess'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I get the response when i comment out the validation and mail function and I think the problem lies with my validation. please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're displaying errors properly in your form, replace your `session('error')` block with the following:

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

In your controller:

```php
use App\Mail\Contact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function contact(Request $request)
    {
        // Note I'm not overwriting the $request variable.
        // This method returns an array of the validated data.
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|max:1000'
        ]);

        Mail::to('support@mail.com')->send(new Contact($request));

        return back()->with('success', 'Your email has successfully been sent');
    }
}
```

Your mail class should look something like this:

```php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        // The request instance must be passed to the view...
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact', [
            'request' => $this->request
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can now use the `Request` object in your email markdown (`emails.contact`). For example:

```
**Name**<br>
{{ $request->input('name') }}

**Email**<br>
{{ $request->input('email') }}

**Message**<br>
{{ $request->input('message') }}
```

Comment: No I do not get a 500 error, i just don't get any response at all and I tried this and it still did not work

Comment: You’re probably getting a validation error then. `session('error')` is not how you output errors in the view. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: Yes I do get an error like:
Undefined variable: request (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lullaby\resources\views\emails\contact.blade.php

Comment: Mail Class
``public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact');
    }
}``

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and correct everything I can see that's wrong with your code. I haven't tested this so there may be issues with it.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your  issue :)